# How to cancel and pause a download using pytube?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pytube

I am working on a GUI YouTube Video Downloader program using python, tkinter and pytube , now i want to know how can I cancel the download and also pause it then unpause it using pytube.

Comment: You can try `pytube.request.stream()` to get an iterable stream, then you can use `next()` to get the stream chunk by chunk.  So you can cancel, pause and resume the download as you wish.

Comment: #acw1668 can you explain it in brief what do you want to say please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example:

- using `pytube.request.stream()` to get an *iterable* stream
- using `next()` to get the video chunk by chunk

```py
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from pytube import YouTube, request

is_paused = is_cancelled = False

def download_video(url):
    global is_paused, is_cancelled
    download_button['state'] ='disabled'
    pause_button['state'] ='normal'
    cancel_button['state'] ='normal'
    try:
        progress['text'] = 'Connecting ...'
        yt = YouTube(url)
        stream = yt.streams.first()
        filesize = stream.filesize  # get the video size
        with open('sample.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            is_paused = is_cancelled = False
            stream = request.stream(stream.url) # get an iterable stream
            downloaded = 0
            while True:
                if is_cancelled:
                    progress['text'] = 'Download cancelled'
                    break
                if is_paused:
                    continue
                chunk = next(stream, None) # get next chunk of video
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    downloaded += len(chunk)
                    progress['text'] = f'Downloaded {downloaded} / {filesize}'
                else:
                    # no more data
                    progress['text'] = 'Download completed'
                    break
        print('done')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    download_button['state'] ='normal'
    pause_button['state'] ='disabled'
    cancel_button['state'] ='disabled'

def start_download():
    threading.Thread(target=download_video, args=(url_entry.get(),), daemon=True).start()

def toggle_download():
    global is_paused
    is_paused = not is_paused
    pause_button['text'] = 'Resume' if is_paused else 'Pause'

def cancel_download():
    global is_cancelled
    is_cancelled = True

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("YouTube Downloader")

tk.Label(root, text='URL:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
url_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=60)
url_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

download_button = tk.Button(root, text='Download', width=20, command=start_download)
download_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='e', padx=10, pady=(0,10))

pause_button = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', width=10, command=toggle_download, state='disabled')
pause_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

progress = tk.Label(root)
progress.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')

cancel_button = tk.Button(root, text='Cancel', width=10, command=cancel_download, state='disabled')
cancel_button.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='e')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey, I need one more help, when I download around four video simultaneously by using different threads for all and pause the download, then my tkinter window starts lagging and after some time it stop working, can you suggest something for this ?

Comment: Try changing `if is_paused: continue` to `if is_paused: time.sleep(0.5)`.

Comment: hey, need one more help when i pause the download for a long time i got this error: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host                                                                                                                            on this line: chunk = next(stream_two, None)  # get next chunk of video